# Python pygame Detect if mouse is over non transparent part of surface

Tags: python, opengl, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to make a UI for my game and there are some curves to the UI. Now I can detect collision between two surfaces. I can detect by pixel between two sprites, but it seems mouse detection by pixel is alluding me. Basically I want to detect when the mouse is over the UI and then ignore everything below that while getting the UI.

This is a picture of what I have so far. If you notice the pink square the mouse is over the GUI while the yellow selector box is over a tile. The yellow selector is a box frame over a tile.

I am using pygame with openGL but at this point I am looking for ANY solution to this. I can adapt pretty easily as I am not new to programming and pretty much looking for any solution.
Also I would post the code but to much code to post so if thing specific is needed let me know.

One thing to note is that the GUI is flexable in that the upper left area will slide in and out. Also the white is just placeholder so final colors are not used and would be difficult to check. Is it possible to get the surface elements under the mouse when clicked by z order?

**Texture**

```
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

class Texture(object):
    image = None
    rect = None
    src = ''
    x = 0
    y = 0
    '''
    zOrder Layers
    0  - background
    1  - 
    2  - 
    3  - Tile Selector
    s  - Tiles
    5  - 
    6  - 
    7  - Panels
    8  - Main Menu
    9  - GUI Buttons
    10 - 

    '''

    def __init__(self, src):
        self.src = src
        self.image = pygame.image.load(src)
        self.image.set_colorkey(pygame.Color(255,0,255,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        texdata = pygame.image.tostring(self.image,"RGBA",0)
        # create an object textures
        self.texid = glGenTextures(1)

        # bind object textures 
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texid)

        # set texture filters
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

        # Create texture image
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,self.rect.w,self.rect.h,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texdata)


        self.newList = glGenLists(2)
        glNewList(self.newList, GL_COMPILE)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texid)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0 ,0)
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, self.rect.h, 0)
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(self.rect.w, self.rect.h, 0)
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(self.rect.w, 0, 0)

        glEnd()
        glEndList()

    def getImg(self):
        return self.image

    def getPos(self):
        rect = self.getImg().get_rect()
        pos = dict(x=self.x,y=self.y,w=rect[2],h=rect[3])
        return pos

    def draw(self,x,y,rotate=0):
        glLoadIdentity()
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y-self.rect.h+32)

        glTranslatef(x,y-self.rect.h+32,0)

        glPushAttrib(GL_TRANSFORM_BIT)
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glRotatef(rotate,0,0,1)
        glPopAttrib()

        if glIsList(self.newList):
            glCallList(self.newList)
```

**gui Class**

```
import hashlib, string, pygame
from classes.texture import Texture

'''
Created on Jun 2, 2013

@author: Joel
'''

class gui(object):
    INSTANCES = 0           # Count of instances of buildings
    ID = 0                  # Building ID
    TYPE = 0                # Building type
    NAME = ''               # name of Building
    DESCRIPTION = ''        # Description of building
    IMAGE = ''              # Image name of building 

    zOrder = 0
    clickable = True

    def __init__(self, Game, name = 'Building', description = '', image = 'panel'):
        self.INSTANCES += 1
        self.setName(name)
        self.setDescription(description)
        self.setImage(Game, Game.SETTING["DIR"]["IMAGES"] + Game.SETTING["THEME"] + '\\gui\\'+image+'.png')
        self.setType(name.lower())
        self.setZ(6)

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.DESCRIPTION

    def setDescription(self, description):
        self.DESCRIPTION = description

    def getID(self):
        return self.ID

    def setID(self, i):
        allchr = string.maketrans('','')
        nodigits = allchr.translate(allchr, string.digits)
        s = hashlib.sha224(i).hexdigest()
        s = s.translate(allchr, nodigits)
        self.ID = s[-16:]

    def getImage(self):
        return self.IMAGE

    def setImage(self, Game, i):
        self.IMAGE = Texture(Game.CWD + '\\' + i)

    def getName(self):
        return self.NAME

    def setName(self, name):
        self.NAME = name

    def getType(self):
        return self.TYPE

    def setType(self, t):
        self.TYPE = t

    def click(self, x, y):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
            if x > self.x and x < (self.x + self.rect.w):
                if y > self.y and y < (self.y + self.rect.h):
                    print("Clicked: " + str(self.x) + ', ' + str(self.y) + ', ' + str(self.rect.w) + ', ' + str(self.rect.y))

    def getClickable(self):
        return self.clickable

    def setClickable(self, c):
        self.clickable = c

    def getZ(self):
        return self.zOrder

    def setZ(self, z):
        self.zOrder = z
```

[image: pygame]

Comment: this is not a flat file code, There are a few pieces here and there. What specifically would you need to see. I could provide all of it but would be a bit overkill.

Comment: the relevant code.  you said you are not new to programming, so I'm confident you can easily isolate the appropriate bits and post them here.

Comment: already have :). Yes I am not new to programming as I have done it for the past 16 years. I also do it professionally as a Web Developer for large companies. Isolating is not hard to do, it whether or not I am lazy or not to do it, ha ha ha.

Comment: aha.  im still debugging it, but i think it has something to do with this line `#How I wish I could be there with you, but distance has kept us apart. Apart physically, but in spirit, you are always in my heart.  `   

i'll get back to you

Comment: That is epic. Last time I use my editor for copy paste of convos. ha ha ha, yeah that's not an issue. Nice pointing it out though.

Comment: Try asking this guy: http://blog.vim.pl/2012/04/gra-izometryczna-cz-7-mysz-w-swiecie-izometrii/

you seem to have similar coding styles and speak the same language.  i imagine he can help you rather quickly

Comment: I actually grabbed his isometric code. Similar means almost direct copy. Well direct copy in most areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I am thinking of this as the best option rather then some of the alternatives. Will keep everyone up to date if this works or not.

global click variable to store data in a dict
Objects have layer variable ranging from 1 to ? from lowest to greatest layer(similar to html zIndex)

1. Primary Loop

   1. reset the global click var
   2. click event get position
2. loop over clickable objects to get everything under mouse

   1. loop over everything under mouse to get highest layer
   2. Return for global click var
3. run click code in object.

Layer organization currently which can be modified.

zOrder Layers

1. background
2. na
3. Tiles
4. Tile Selector
5. na
6. na
7. Panels
8. Main Menu
9. GUI Buttons
10. na

**Loop**

```
for i in range(len(self.OBJECTS)):
    #img = Texture(see op)
    img = self.OBJECTS[i].IMAGE
    print(img)
    e = None
    if self.OBJECTS[i].zOrder == 4: # is isometric image
        # tx and ty are translated positions for screen2iso. See Below
        if ((self.tx >= 0 and self.tx < self.SETTING['MAP_WIDTH']) and (self.ty >= 0 and self.ty < self.SETTING['MAP_HEIGHT'])):
            # map_x and map_y are starting points for the map its self.
            ix, iy = self.screen2iso(
                (x - (self.map_x + (self.SETTING['TILE_WIDTH'] / 2))),
                (y - (self.map_y))
            )
            imgx, imgy = self.screen2iso(
                (img.x - (self.map_x + (self.SETTING['TILE_WIDTH'] / 2))),
                (img.y - (self.map_y))
            )
            if (imgx+2) == ix:
                if (imgy+1) == iy:
                    e = self.OBJECTS[i]
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
    else: # Not an isometric image
        if x > img.x and x < (img.x + img.rect[2]):
            if y > img.y and y < (img.y + img.rect[3]):
                #is click inside of visual area of image?
                if self.getCordInImage(x, y, self.OBJECTS[i].IMAGE):
                    if self.getAlphaOfPixel(self.OBJECTS[i]) != 0:
                        e = self.OBJECTS[i]
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    if e != None:
        if self.CLICKED['zOrder'] < e.getZ():
            self.CLICKED['zOrder'] = e.getZ()
            self.CLICKED['e'] = e
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
```

**getCordInImage**

```
def getCordInImage(self, x, y, t):
    return [x - t.x, y - t.y]
```

**getAlphaOfPixel**

```
def getAlphaOfPixel(self, t):
    mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x,y = self.getCordInImage(mx,my,t.IMAGE)
    #mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(t.IMAGE.image)
    return t.IMAGE.image.get_at([x,y])[3]
```

**screen2iso**

```
def screen2iso(self, x, y):
    x = x / 2
    xx = (y + x) / (self.SETTING['TILE_WIDTH'] / 2)
    yy = (y - x) / (self.SETTING['TILE_WIDTH'] / 2)
    return xx, yy
```

**iso2screen**

```
def iso2screen(self, x, y):
    xx = (x - y) * (self.SETTING['TILE_WIDTH'] / 2)
    yy = (x + y) * (self.SETTING['TILE_HEIGHT'] / 2)
    return xx, yy
```

Comment: This actually worked pretty well for my needs as the Entire UI can not be merged together as there are elements on top of each other and such and I need to get individual pieces due to the many pieces with this. I will update my answer soon with some code for future lookers. Right now I need to get click through on a surface with mouse pos and alpha which I am working on next.

Comment: Done and updated my posts for future people looking for similar code. The code needs refactoring but I can do that later on. :D

Answer (score 2):

You could create a mask of the UI (this would be easiest if the UI is contained in one surface which is then applied to the screen surface), and set the threshold of the mask to the appropriate value so that your transparent pixels are set to `0` in the mask.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface

With the mask object's `get_at((x,y))` function you can test if a specific pixel of the mask is set (a non-zero value is returned if the pixel is set).

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.get_at

If you pass in the mouse's position, you can verify that it is over a visible part of the UI if you receive a non-zero value.

Comment: only thing is it will have multiple surfaces and the surfaces will be manipulated in that the upper left will slide in and out

Comment: In that case I would combine the surfaces into one surface prior to creating the mask (and also prior to rendering).  You would probably do this once per frame, or at least every time you have reason to believe the UI surfaces have changed.  Let me know if you'd like to know how to do that.

Comment: Would it be able to get the items that are clicked on? Then I can check if it is in that list?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible answers:

1) Statically create a 2D array of True or False that is as big as the screen - True if clicking here would click on the UI, False if clicking here would not click on the UI. Test clicks against the position in this array.

2) Use the 'paint and check' algorithm (don't recall the real name). You know how when you draw to the screen you draw the background, then background objects, then foreground objects? You can use a similar trick to detect what object you have clicked on - draw the background in one solid colour, each object in another solid colour, each UI element in another solid colour, etc... and as long as each solid colour is unique, you can test what colour pixel is under the cursor in this buffer and use it to determine what was visible and clicked on by the mouse.

Comment: i like the second approach

Comment: One thing to note is that the GUI is flexable in that the upper left area will slide in and out. Also the white is just placeholder so final colors are not used and would be difficult to check. Is it possible to get the surface elements under the mouse when clicked by z order?

Comment: @Phreak Nation Solution 2) is designed to deal with exactly your problem, where the layout of the screen is changing (objects moving around, obscuring other objects, etc) and you want to find out what was clicked on. And the solution is simple - you draw eveery single thing that can be seen on screen, the same way you'd normally draw it on screen (with regards to what obscures what, etc), except you draw each object as a solid colour and remember what colour you used. When you're done, what colour under the cursor indicates what object was frontmost (visible) under the cursor.

Comment: What if no solid colors are used? Unless your talking about drawing a second view with solid colors and in that case would not be very good on the performance side of things. I had a third thought. Making an array for the gui and check if a boolean value is true or not, if it is do checks for that where as get the mask in relation to the mouse then if the mouse is not over that area go to the next layer down. Essentially Menu > Panel > Game area

Comment: @PhreakNation Actually, drawing is really really fast if you do it through OpenGL functions, modern GPUs are incredibly good at drawing rapidly and in a parallel manner. And if you're only interested in 'which element of the UI did you click on or did you click on no element of the UI' you can save even more time by only drawing UI elements to this second view (yes, that's what I mean, you draw a temporary frame with solid colour versions of the objects, check which the cursor hit, then you draw the real frame)

Comment: I like that method as its a pretty good one but there has got to be a more direct way of getting what the user clicked on as this will be a pretty in depth GUI with multiple actions and pieces. I will def consider this as a fallback but only if I can not get what a user is clicking on more directly.